# Is there any way to display github user name in prompt

Tags: bash, github, osx-mountain-lion, command-prompt

Sometimes I have to work with multiple Github accounts. Different email and name. And what happens all the time is I accidentally commit with wrong user and everything this messes up everything (scenario is both the users have access to that repo but one user is wrong). So to avoid this I want to display github user email in prompt.

`export PS1=$(git config user.email)`

Above bashrc entry works but it doesn't update itself when I `cd` to a Github repo with different github email and username setup.

I am on mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather, set it as

```sh
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=$(git config user.email)'
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/177b8e0/.exports#L7)

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
    If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary 
    prompt.
```

[`bash(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: Great man, it works. Thanks a lot. How this works can you explain a bit?